# "Have seen" vs "saw"?

Tags: present-perfect

> I **have seen** a plane.

Here, what is the meaning of the sentence above? I understand the basic meaning of 'have pp'. The sentence above means that
I **have just seen a plane**? Or I **have seen a plane before**? Or **both** according to the context?

Comment: This question has been answered many, many times on this site.

Comment: Oh..I should have checked out first..anyway, feel very very grateful to get answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the meaning comes from context - what this is in response to.

In isolation it seems a strange thing to say unprovoked, and might get a response of 'Well, who hasn't?'.

If it is in response to 'What have you seen through the window?' then it has your first meaning - 'just seen'. If it's in response to 'Hey- that's a plane! Did you know that?' then depending on intonation and emphasis it could be a sarcastic or patient reply in your second sense.

So yes, it could mean either depending on context.